# How to respond to "Are you looking for a job change?" question form an acquaintance on LinkedIn?

Tags: professionalism, recruitment, job-change, job-hopping

One of my LinkedIn contacts recently messaged me if I was looking for a job change. He is not a recruiter but a principal engineer in some firm. He appears to know some senior people at my current employment because in the same message, he mentioned some names and asked how they were doing and all. 
I am looking for a job change for sure, but quite hesitant to answer this direct question, since dont know the person personally.

Comment: I noticed you have ~15% acceptance rate for the answers to your questions: Can you clarify if existing answers are not satisfactory?

Comment: Dear Sourav, I recently got little active and learning the forum rules/practices.  I am satisfied with the answers. In fact I have replied to the person based on your answer.

Comment: I'm not talking about my answers, it's overall. Also read: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062)

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I will revisit answers to my previous questions to ensure compliance to this guideline.

Comment: You're most welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 15):

If you are not comfortable with being straightforward and want to play diplomatic, you can answer something like:

> *"I'm not actively looking for a change right now, but I'm open to discussions".*

Then, if the discussion starts, you can actually show interest. There's nothing wrong in that.

Comment: or "Just keeping an eye on the job market to make sure I'm not being underpaid", which implies that you would move if you got a better offer.